# Is it possible to skip cut scenes

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

For the intro to the game, all of the DLC intros and outros, and the ending to the entire game is it possible to skip the cut scenes. I have beaten the game so I have seen them all already and I don't have the desire to sit through them again.

I'm playing on PC if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you confirm you mean the actual cut scenes, and not just the "acted scenes" where the NPCs move around and do thing, and you see it from the perspective of your character?

The cut scenes themselves are skippable, but you shouldn't need to ask how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/56651/?) appears to do what you want.